# Check if all of array items are undefined or empty string

Tags: javascript

How to check if all of `items` are `undefined` or empty string `''`?

```
var items = [variable_1, variable_2, variable_3];
```

Is there any nice way to do that instead of big `if`? Not ES6.

Comment: There's a `.every()` method on the Array prototype. (edited)

Comment: `items.every(function(item) { return item === undefined || item === '' })` is ES5.1 -- or you could just check for falsey-ness (which includes null, empty strings, undefined, etc) `!item`

Comment: Actually, it's `.every`. `.all` is not standard JS, it's probably some library you've used

Comment: Use `.every()` or `.filter()` depending on what you want to do (test all values or only get the values that have some value you care about).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
>   test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner that uses Array.prototype.some to find at least one element which is not undefined or '', if it finds one it returns true

```
!items.some(item => item != undefined || item != '')
```

Comment: Consider using strict comparison, i.e. `!==`. Also, arrow functions are ES6. OP doesn't want ES6

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one I just thought of:

```
if (array.join("") === "") 
  // all undefined or ""
```

Note that that'll also be `true` if an element is `null`, not `undefined`, so it may or may not suit the OP. Advantage is that it doesn't need a callback function.